# Dialog position

Tags: jquery, dialog

I am trying to change the left position for a dialog box created with jQuery, but it does not seems to recognize the new value; here is my code:

```
            $('#settype_dialog').dialog({
                                            autoOpen: true,
                                            width: 200,
                                            height: 200,
                                            show: 'bounce',
                                            hide: 'puff'
                                        }
            );
            $('#settype_dialog').css({"left", cX});
            $('#settype_dialog').dialog('option', 'title', 'Select Set Type');
            $('#settype_dialog').html(xml_text);
            $('#settype_dialog').dialog('open');
```

Where cX is 130

Answer (score 1):

Well, incorrect syntax looks to be the cause of your problem.
The `css()` method of the jQuery object accepts either an object of key/value pairs where key is the property, or a `property, value` signature.

The two following ways would be equivalent:

```
$('#settype_dialog').css({"left": cX});
```

or

```
$('#settype_dialog').css("left", cX);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append "px". `cX + "px"`

Comment: Nah. If a number value is passed in, the CSS method automagically adds the `px` suffix. See lines 42-44 of http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/css.js

Comment: Hmm. Interesting to know. Thanks!